# html.beingform not generating appropriate url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

I am using html.beingform to generate the url to post

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "ctrl", new { id = 5, name = "a" }))
```

the url getting generated is

```
<form action="/ctrl/action/5?name=a" method="post">
```

but it should be generated as

```
<form action="/ctrl/action?name=a&id=5" method="post">
```

what is wrong with the syntax I am using??

**EDIT**

I tried below syntax as per comments

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "ctrl", new { [id] = 5, name = "a" }))
```

above gave me error

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "ctrl", new { @id = 5, name = "a" }))
```

above did still added it to url

Comment: I would first try with `[id] = 5` as `id` has a particular meaning to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: The default route already defines an optional `id` parameter so it is being added to the route instead of querystring.

Comment: @AndyG it did not work, check comments

Comment: @Crowcoder so how to get around this limitation?

Comment: In your RegisterRoutes method you should have a call to MapRoute that adds it. You can just remove it there.

Comment: @Crowcoder is there some other way to achieve it, I wont be able to modify MapRoute.

Comment: Can you change the signature of the Action so it's parameter is not named `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

even with url like:

```
 <form action="/ctrl/action/5?name=a" method="post">
```

the action does work as intended, because the route definition does assign 5 to id, hence this is not an issue.

still keeping the question open, it can help someone in future

**EDIT**

this is another way to solve it

- define another route definition without "id"
- and call Html.BeginRouteForm("newRoute", new {id = 5, name = "abcd"})